# GoogleMap and getMapAsync

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to find a way to implement properly `getMapAsync()` in my code where I will have to deal a lot with google `Marker`. As you may know the `getMapAsync()` returns a non-null map when this one is ready in `onMapReady`.

So basically I will have to do all my stuff about the markers in `onMapReady`. The problem is that in various pieces of my code I call my google markers initialised in `onMapReady` with `map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions())` but I can't know if these markers are already initialised or not (well I can add a `boolean` in `onMapReady` to know if my `Marker` where initialised but in the case where this boolean is `false` what am I supposed to do? Do nothing with my markers?).

So basically I would like to be able to get the same behaviours as the synchronous `getMap()` method **but** where I'll be sure to get a non-null map. As I'm pretty sure I can't add a "waiter" on my main thread (such as `CountdownLatch`) I can't find a way to wait for the map to be ready before continuing in the rest of the code in my main thread. Thank you

Comment: obvious solution call "adding code" from both places (creation of marker and onMapReady) ... in "adding code" check if map is ready, if not, store marker in some list of markers variable(field) ... if map is ready add marker and add all markers from list, clear list ... of course add some thread race check

Comment: `if not, store marker in some list of markers variable(field)`

The markers instances are retrieved with `map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions())`, The `map` need to be initialised if I want to have a `Marker` instance.

Comment: hmm ok, ok ... so store list of MarkerOptions or other data needed to their creation ... but you get the general conception? you need something like pending markers(or data for their creation) to add ...

Comment: That's what I did. But Imagine I do: `myMarkerOption.icon(xx)` on my `MarkerOption` instance, I don't think it will be automatically fired to its appropriate `Marker` on the map (whether it has been initialised or not), will it?

Comment: Storing the `MarkerOption` in a var is not viable to me as using its setters won't reflect the changes on the `Marker`

Answer (score 0):

The solution was indeed as @Selvin stated, to manipulate and store a `MarkerOptions` variable. To reflect the changes of the `MarkerOptions` variables into my map I created a method like the following:

```
public void reloadMarkersOnTheMap() {
    if (isMapInitialised) {
        map.clear();
        map.addMarker(pickupMarker);
        map.addMarker(dropOffMarker);
    }
}
```

The solution is then to clear and re-add my `Marker` from/to the `GoogleMap` with the modified value of my `MarkerOptions` variables. If `isMapInitialised == false` then my markers will be initialised with their latest modifications in `onMapReady()`